# LAN screen sharing with view-only and auto-reconnect

Tags: windows, screen-sharing

My setup will be, two laptops connected via LAN (via a router using either Wi-Fi or wired). One is known as viewer and another one is known as server. The viewer laptop will be the one that 'views' what is going on on the server laptop.

These are my requirements:

1. Auto-reconnect immediately when connection becomes available.
2. On the viewer laptop, able to set the viewing to full screen without any icon or toolbars showing.
3. Able to prevent the viewer from controlling the server laptop (only can view).
4. Does not give errors popups in viewer or server laptop whenever connection is lost.
5. Able to set connection retries/timeout value
6. Able to work over LAN
7. Compatible with Windows 10 Pro.

So far the only software that I've found that meets the most requirements is UltraVNC. It only fails requirement #4 but I still can't use it because all requirements are crucial to the business.

Comment: Please give some more details! e.g.: Operating System(s)? Price? Licence?

Comment: @SteveBarnes I've added Operating System. But you can assume that all other details that are not listed down does not matter.

Comment: Just curious, but what should happen on #4 ? Blank screen on the client, or at least sits own screen - just no indication of error?  Would you use UltraVCN ( lovely bit of software), if you could also find some "auto-click" software to detect and close any error popups? If so, and any of you can code, then AutoIt could that in about three lines of code. If not, ask a new question here, requesting auto click & close. Btw, you didn't make it clear in your question that this is for commercial use, which might preclude some answers.

Comment: @Mawg Yes, I've heard of AutoIt but I would prefer the solution to be built-in. UltraVNC + AutoIt was to be my last resort. Btw, it is strange that UltraVNC allows auto-reconnect but still require manual intervention (closing the 'connection lost!' dialog box) in order to trigger it.

Comment: Good luck with your search. At least you have a fall-back position.

Answer (score 1):

Turning the thinking around rather than looking for a desktop sharing program that doesn't allow any control over the master computer from the slave you can simply broadcast a video stream of what is happening on the master computer.

I would suggest taking a look at [VideoLAN](https://www.videolan.org/)'s [VLC](https://www.videolan.org/vlc/download-windows.en-GB.html) for both streaming and displaying.

Your requirements:

1. Auto-reconnect immediately when connection becomes available. *duplicate of 4*
2. On the viewer laptop, able to set the viewing to full screen without any icon or toolbars showing. **YES**
3. Able to prevent the viewer from controlling the server laptop (only can view). ***Yes*** *Since you are broadcasting a video this is **not** an issue*
4. Does not give errors popups in viewer or server laptop whenever connection is lost. *The server doesn't care, it is broadcasting, whether anybody is listening or not, for the slave you should be able to do this with the correct command line options, [this](https://wiki.videolan.org/Documentation:Streaming_HowTo/Command_Line_Examples/#Keeping_the_stream_open) may help.*
5. Able to set connection retries/timeout value *duplicate of 4*
6. Able to work over LAN ***Definitely***
7. Compatible with Windows 10 Pro. ***Yes*** and just about everything else from Windows XP SP3 to the last version of Windows 10 plus OS-X & Linux.

There is a walk-through [here](https://www.howtogeek.com/118075/how-to-stream-videos-and-music-over-the-network-using-vlc/) of how to set the broadcast up just set the capture device to desktop.

Comment: Looks plausible. Will accept this answer after I've tested it out and deemed successful.